# how to convert timedelta64[ns] to int?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert timedelta64[ns] to int

timedelta64[ns] example :
01:00:00 , 02:00:00 , 03:00:00 , 04:00:00

I want to convert as : 1, 2 , 3 , 4

Help me please T^T

Comment: Simply do type casting, float(str())

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
 t, _ , _ = "01:00:00".split(":")
```

and then:

```
int(t)
```

That will return you: 1.

Putting this together as a function would be:

```
def time_to_integer(time):
    t, _,_ = time.split(":")
    return int(t)
```

Please note that you should pass the *time* variable as string. For example:

```
time_to_integer("02:00:00")
```

Would return: 2

Answer (score 2):

```
In [106]: t = pd.to_timedelta(['01:12:34', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00'])

In [107]: t.seconds // 3600
Out[107]: Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```